# Why is `(exit)` not always available in the REPL?

Tags: clojure, exit, leiningen

Today I noticed something odd.  When I'm not "in" a project (that is, the shell is not in a clojure project's directory), I **can** use `exit` to exit the REPL:

```
shell$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 43712
user=> (+ 3 4)
7
user=> (exit)
shell$ echo '<span>not in <s>kansas</s>clojure anymore</span>'
```

When I'm "in" a project (that is, the shell is in a clojure project's directory), I **can't** use `exit`:

```
shell$ cd my_clojure_project
shell$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 69237
user=> (* 8 4)
32
user=> (exit)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: exit in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)
user=>
```

**What is the issue here?**

---

Clojure version (for both examples):

```
user=> (clojure-version)
"1.2.1"
```

Leiningen version (for both examples):

```
shell$ lein -v
Leiningen 1.6.1 on Java 1.6.0_26 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Comment: Seems fairly apparent that "Exit" merely exits the current "shell."  EXIT-CEPTION.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is unclear, but that's not what I'm asking.  I would like to know why `exit` is **sometimes** in scope, but not all the time.

Comment: I confirmed your problem, but don't know why it's happening. I'm using Clojure 1.3.0 and lein Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_20 OpenJDK Client VM

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be because the `leiningen.core` namespace isn't available when there is a project. More specifically, when there is a project, your project's code is [evaluated in a separate ClassLoader](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/1.x/src/leiningen/compile.clj#L200) with only your project on the classpath. Therefore none of Leiningen's functions are available.

The Leiningen 2 REPL doesn't have this problem.